# selenium.attachFile(String fieldLocator, String fileLocator) method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

String fileLocator here is actually a file URL. I define a file URL to 'file:///D:/images/pic1.jpg' but selenium for some reason i don't get tries to load it from c:\Temp (where the TEMP variable defined dir is located for my user) adding this sequence to the original location, so java returns an exception.

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Temp\D:\images\pic1.jpg (Syntax error in filename)
```

That is rather predictable.

So the question is how to make selenium load file directly from the dir i specify or pass it an URL it will not rewrite?

**UPD**

Looks like this thing just **can't** for some reason add files from local file system using 'file' protocol. If i use 'http' it works ok.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The temp path appears before the actual one. Did you get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why selenium tries to open your file form C:\Temp is because if you would have provided the a remote file it would have been downloaded there and after that referenced the local copy.

You could try something like this in order to see that indeed the url is correctly defined:

```
File file = new File (filePath);
selenium.attachFile(fieldLocator, file.toURL().toString());
```

From what I know about the method `attachFile` it only works on Firefox.

Comment: that is what i am doing. except the point that in java6 toURL() method is deprecated and i use toURI().toURL() instead - this leads to the above result.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a question of what Java's `URL.getFile()` can download into a temporary file, because that's what Selenium RC uses to get the file.  If I had to guess, I'd say that your `file://D:/images/pic1.jpg` is being blocked by some file-access-control mechanism (e.g., permission bits, Java security profiles, etc.).  Of course, perhaps your script is running on machine X and Selenium RC is running on machine Y?  If so, then the file really **isn't** accessible.

Selenium expects a URL because there is no rule requiring the browser (under RC's control) and the test script to be on the same system.  Some outfits, like [Sauce Labs](http://saucelabs.com) and [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com), depend on this capability.